# Custom libinput quirk for Apple Magic Trackpad 2

Tags: bluetooth, touchpad

I have a common problem with Apple Magic Trackpad 2: it requires quite a lot of pressure to work fine when connected via bluetooth (using USB everything is ok). As mentioned here https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/issues/280 this behavior can be changed by changing libinput configuration for the device.

The desired config for the device looks like this, with `AttrTouchSize` & `AttrTouchPressureRange` attributes responsible for that.

```
[Apple Magic Trackpad v2 Bluetooth (new vendor ID)]
MatchBus=bluetooth
MatchVendor=0x004C
MatchProduct=0x0265
AttrTouchSizeRange=20:10
AttrTouchPressureRange=3:0
AttrPalmSizeThreshold=900
AttrThumbSizeThreshold=700
```

Default configuration is stored in the following location:

```
/usr/share/libinput/50-system-apple.quirks
```

But there's a note in the config file:

```
# Do not edit this file, it will be overwritten on update
```

The question is - how to properly set up custom configuration for this particular device? Should I create a new .quirk or edit the default one?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved.

1. You can't change default quirks. So you need to create `/usr/share/libinput/local-overrides.quirks` (with this particular name) and specify the desired config there.
2. `AttrTouchPressureRange` is incorrect attribute name (despite that it's the name given in official docs https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/device-quirks.html#device-quirks). The proper name is `AttrPressureRange`, I had to check the following docs page: https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/touchpad-pressure-debugging.html#touchpad-pressure-hwdb.

Comment: #2 doc issue is solved as of *libinput 1.17.0*